# Echo data in custom place in while method

Tags: php, sql

Am using this method to display data from `SQL`, this code will display 2 rows random from `SQL` database it works perfect but my problem is i want to display data in custom location like `<?php echo $row[id] ?>`

can someone help me to echo like  `<?php echo $row[id] ?>`

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sanoj";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sanojtable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Status</th><th>Time In Progress</th><th>Est Time of Completion</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["link"]." ".$row["piclink"]."</td><td>".$row["cat"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

HOwW do i echo like this

```
<div>
        row ONE echo data
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['link'] . " " . $row['piclink'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['cat'] ?></td></tr>   
    </div>
    <div>
        row TWO echo data
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['link'] . " " . $row['piclink'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['cat'] ?></td></tr>   
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create a dynamic array for later reuse within the while loop:

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //add the next line - this saves data for reuse
        $custom_id[]=$row["id"];
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["link"]." ".$row["piclink"]."</td><td>".$row["cat"]."</td></tr>";
    }
```

Then after your table prints out, you can use either all data or just one row whenever you want in the page like this:

```
    echo $custom_id[0];
    echo $custom_id[1];
```

If you want to reuse all id from the previous loop, you use

```
    foreach($custom_id as $id){
       echo $id;
    }
```

If you do not want the table in the place where you have the while loop, you just store data in an array. Instead of:

```
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["link"]." ".$row["piclink"]."</td><td>".$row["cat"]."</td></tr>";
```

you just create array:

```
    my_id[]= $row["id"];
```

then you just print an array element

```
    <?php echo my_id[0];?>
```

or, as alternative, you can create a string for each row, like:

```
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //create a string variable from table
        $html_row[] = "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["link"]." ".$row["piclink"]."</td><td>".$row["cat"]."</td></tr>";
    }
```

in this case you print row 1 in one place:

```
    <?php echo $html_row[0]; ?>
```

and row 2 in another place:

```
    <?php echo $html_row[1]; ?>
```

Because the key in the automatic array begin with 0, your first row has key [0]

For you code, you use this:

```
    <div>
         row ONE echo data
        <?php echo $html_row[0]; ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        row TWO echo data
        <?php echo $html_row[1]; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: i need to echo two rows in tow different places how do i do that

Comment: You can use it in any place  `<? echo $custom_id[0];?>` - for the first line, and  `<? echo $custom_id[1];?>` for the second line. Just echo one of these anywhere in the page after the table and it will work.

Comment: Or, if you do not want to print the table in the while loop, you can just create an array within the loop, and then echo it later.

Comment: You should try that outside the loop. You do not echo inside the while loop. I edited my answer, i think you need what is in my latest edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {?>
     <table>
       <tr><th>ID</th>
       <th>Status</th>
       <th>Time In Progress</th>
       <th>Est Time of Completion</th>
     </tr>
     <?php 
            // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
           <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['link']." ".$row['piclink']?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['cat']?></td></tr>
         <?php  }?> </table>
           <?php } else {
            echo "0 results";
           }
```

i think you want this correct me if i am wrong

Comment: am trying to echo two rows above code echo does that , but i need to echo two rows in two different place